# how to insert Image in collection view After 4 row?

Tags: swift

**Description** -> i have to set 4 static image in first 4 row of collectionView and after that i have to set image in collection view from Api  ?

Any Suggestion?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
return DemoImageArrary.count
}

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius =  20
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect:cell.bounds, cornerRadius:cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath
  //  let Thumnails = DemoImageArrary[indexPath.row]
    cell.ThumnailImage.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: DemoImageArrary[indexPath.row]))
    return cell
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let padding: CGFloat =  20    
    let collectionViewSize = collectionView.frame.size.width - padding
    return CGSize(width: collectionViewSize/2, height: collectionViewSize/2)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes but i didn't get any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **cellForRowAtIndexpath** method of **UITableView**

write

```
if indexPath.row >= 3 {
//indexPath.row gives you the row index 
  // set image of first four rows like
tableCell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(yourLocalImageNamesArray[indexPath.row])")

}else{
  // set image from api like
  tableCell.YourImageView.image = UIImage(named: "\(yourApiImageNamesArray[indexPath.row])")
}
```